# How to build zeromq4-haskell with local zmq?

Tags: haskell, zeromq, failed-installation

I want to be able to build `zeromq4-haskell` or build a project that depends on `zeromq4-haskell` without ZeroMQ installed in my system.

In other words,
I want a command `stack build zeromq4-haskell` to succeed and compile with my local version of ZeroMQ. I have already tried setting the **`LIBRARY_PATH`** and **`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** to a directory, which is containing **`libzmq.so`**,
but without any luck.

My goal is to build a project, depending on ZeroMQ, on a client's machine that might not have ZeroMQ installed or doesn't have rights to install it with a package manager.

Comment: What error do you get - I am fresh out of crystal balls, so I cannot check myself, what errors you get.

Comment: do you want to build it on a client machine or run it? - usually for building you need more dependencies which are then part of the application.